# Need help identifying unknown fixture on basement ceiling

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I was just wondering if anyone knew what this fixture is. It is 3.5" in diameter and about 1.5" deep.
Any help would be greatly appreciated[image][image]

Comment: Would you know where the other end of that cable goes.  With the screw adjustment showing in the hole, a guess might be a rheostat/dimmer type device for something.

Comment: Two screws secure the flat cover. Remove the screw in the little slot (on the right in the pictures), then loosen the the other screw, then pivot the flat cover around the loosened screw so we can see what's inside the box.

Comment: Be sure to turn off power first or at least have a non-contact voltage tester to make sure you're not touching energized metal before you open up the cover.

Comment: It's just a junction box, not a fixture. It's where the ceiling light used to be when the ceiling used to be *there*. What's the objective here, other than putting a cover with no knockout on it, and a fitting on the flexible? These days they're octagon; used to be circular. I see the 'ceiling fan' tag. I guess that's fine if you put some screws in the bracket. If it was a modern octagon it would need to become a modern fan box with supports; you pretty much have that going for you already.

Comment: @Mazura  The second picture is the important one, the first picture does not show enough.  Something is inside that looks like an adjustment/setting screw in the second.  A picture of the inside would be nice.

Comment: Oh. That's the hickey holding it to the bracket. Which is why a fan is okay. It is not why there's a hole in the plate; that's for a fitting.

Comment: The stamping on the cover reads `NATL 2BAD` or `NATL 28AD` (I'm leaning toward the former, as amusing as it is). Unfortunately a web search doesn't seem to turn up a particular manufacturer/product by that name. Maybe one of our more experienced electricians can identify the cover plate by those markings.

Answer (score 2):

There's just no telling what used to be attached to that junction box. It reminds me of many such boxes I've seen in basement ceilings that had a doorbell transformer attached to that knockout hole in the cover plate.